# How to count the number of days a patient has spent admitted in a hospital on clicking a discharge button?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a date of admission field for a patient in my database, i have a discharge button which i want to get the number of days a patient has spent in the hospital admitted when a user clicks the discharge button.

Comment: How much far have you come? put some code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Carbon

I suggest you use the Carbon package to complete this. The following link will assit:

[Carbon - Difference](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference)

### Example

```
$dt = Carbon::createMidnightDate(2019, 1, 1);
echo $dt->diffInDays($dt->copy()->addMonth());
```

The above code first sets a carbon instance to a time of 00:00 on the 1st of Jan 2019. It then compares it with `$dt->copy()->addMonth()` (this is the same date + 1 month). Therefore, this will echo out 31 as there are 31 days between the 1st of Jan and the 1st of Feb.

You can just set the $dt to your admission date and the comparison date to `now()`. That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks @Petay87, let me try out this i think it will be a good one.